# Why Graph G2 is not a subgraph isomorphism of graph G1

Tags: python, numpy, networkx, subgraph, isomorphism

[G1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgCfL.png)
[G2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bi5LO.png)
Hi all I am trying to see if G2 is a subgraph isomorphism of G1, if I plot them I can clearly see the isomorphism but the I get False using the function.

```
L =[[ 0,   23.4,  30.3,  49.45,  0,    0,    0,   0,    0,    0,    0],
 [23.4,   0,   34.42, 39.54, 34.26,  0,    0,    0,    0,    0 ,   0  ],
 [30.3,  34.42,  0,   26.67, 42.71, 79.12,  0,    0,    0 ,   0,    0  ],
 [49.45, 39.54 ,26.67,  0,   22.98 ,65.57 ,44.53,  0,    0,    0,    0  ],
 [ 0,  34.26 ,42.71 ,22.98 , 0 ,  43.04 ,23.19, 47.2,   0 ,   0   , 0  ],
 [ 0 ,   0   ,79.12 ,65.57, 43.04,  0,   30.29 ,29.14, 64.72 , 0 ,   0  ],
 [ 0  ,  0    ,0   ,44.53 ,23.19 ,30.29  ,0,   24.19, 60.59, 49.7,   0  ],
 [ 0   , 0   , 0    ,0 ,  47.2  ,29.14 ,24.19 , 0,   39.03 ,46.27 ,40.06],
 [ 0 ,   0  ,  0,    0  ,  0  , 64.72, 60.59 ,39.03 , 0   ,44.72 ,62.05],
 [ 0  ,  0 ,   0 ,   0   , 0 ,   0 ,  49.7  ,46.27 ,44.72 , 0 ,  30.7 ],
 [ 0   , 0,    0  ,  0    ,0,    0  ,  0 ,  40.06, 62.05, 30.7  , 0  ]]



A5 = np.array(L)
A2 = np.array([[30,30,0], [0,30,30], [30,0,30]])


G1 = nx.from_numpy_matrix(A5)
G2 = nx.from_numpy_matrix(A2)
nx.draw(G1)
nx.draw(G2)
plt.show()
GM = isomorphism.GraphMatcher(G1,G2)
print(GM.subgraph_is_isomorphic())
```

Comment: Can you provide plots of the graphs?

Comment: Two graphs of different sizes cannot be isomorphic.

Comment: @IñigoMoreno thats not true

Comment: @Darina Yes, You should be able to see this, thanks for the feedback

Comment: Your first graph has no self-loops and your second graph has three. How can they be isomorphic/monomorphic? Or did you accidentally shuffled the lines for the second graph

Comment: @Sparky05 you are true, by changing the line it worked, Thank you

Comment: @Prova313Ciao313 oh, I didn't see that you said subgraph isomorphic.

Comment: @Prova313Ciao313 you should answer to your question yourself and explain the issue for people who find it on google later.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in The triangle, In the way I've constructed the adjacency matrix, I've accidentally shuffled the lines and I've allowed self-loop. The correct one should be G2 = np.array([[0,30,30],[30,0,30],[30,30,0]]. With this I managed to find the isomorphism.